# Instantiating a passed form of unknown type

Tags: c#, forms, instantiation

I have forms in my application that display a DataGrid bound to a BindingSource. When I double-click on a row I display a detail form.

I have almost 50 of these "browse" forms with their accompanying detail form. I would like to reduce the number of forms (and code) by creating a base browse form and passing the appropriate BindingSource to it. I have this working. However, when I double-click on a row, I want to instantiate the detail form related to the passed BindingSource.

For example, If the user is browsing the Customer table, then a Customer Detail form will be opened, but if he is browsing the Job table, then the Job Detail form will open.

I can pass a generic detail form as a parameter, but how do I cast that passed form to one of the correct type so I can instantiate it?

(I am trying to avoid a large switch statement that cycles through to select the correct passed form. Surely there is a more elegant way to achieve this?)

[EDIT]
My browse form code is instantiated thus:

```
public BaseBrowse(BindingSource dataClass, DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm crudForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bs   = dataClass;
        crud = ((CRUDEquipment)(crudForm));
    }
```

My double-click event is thus:

```
    private void gvw_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 nID = Convert.ToInt32(gvw.GetFocusedRowCellValue("ID"));
        ((CRUDEquipment)(crud)).intID = nID;
        ((CRUDEquipment)(crud)).Show();                
    }
```

I need a way to replace the "CRUDEquipment" with whatever form I need.

Comment: So you form configuration object needs *two* members, the BindingSource and a Type for the detail form.

Comment: I'm actually passing the BindingSource and a copy of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of these will help

```
public void Instantiate<T>()
{
    var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    // Do something with myObject
}

public void Instantiate(Type t)
{
    var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    // Do something with myObject
}

public void Instantiate(string typeName)
{
    var detailType = Type.GetType(typeName);

    if (detailType == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Nice try, but type {0} doesn't compute :)");
    }

    var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(detailType);
    // Do something with myObject
}
```